# Connection refused when running "solr create" from vagrant provision file

Tags: vagrant, apache-solr

I'm trying to create a [CKAN 2.10.1](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.10/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html) instance with vagrant. The code is in this [vagrant-ckan GitHub repository](https://github.com/transparencia-mg/vagrant-ckan/tree/4a91b96c1fc41c1721c0ba03e9ba9b50bf3477e0).

The `vagrant up` calls the `setup/provision_ckan.sh` file, and almost everything goes well, except the Solr create session process. When the `setup/provision_ckan.sh` arives at line 74 (`sudo -u solr /opt/solr/bin/solr create -c ckan`) the `Connect to localhost:8983 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)` error occors and the process didn't finish correctly.

[This stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72716105/connection-refused-when-running-solr-create) answers seems pretty the same mine, but the [acepted anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72719436/11755155) didn't work, unfortunately.

I also tryed [this another stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851416/how-to-fix-error-createing-solrcore-gettingstarted-unable-to-create-core/73964970#73964970) option but nothing.

I believe that this is a possible user permission issue due to the vagrant machine creation process. If yes, how could I fix it? If not, what I'm missing?

Obs.: [CKAN official documentation](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.10/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html#:%7E:text=Run%20the%20installation%20script%20as) recommends run `sudo bash ./install_solr_service.sh solr-8.11.2.tgz` as `root` user. I also tried this option, but the process failed as well.

Comment: Sounds like Solr isn't running. The line before, it is supposed to report the Solr service status. What does it say?

Comment: Hello Daniel, thanks for your help. Slor is indeed running. The `sudo service solr status` says that it's active: `Active: active (exited) since Mon 2023-08-28 20:22:03 UTC; 2min 20s ago`. That's why it is so strange to me. Could it be something related to user permissions?